# Unable to get data from list control

Tags: mfc, clistctrl

I am working with list control in MFC. I have written code to insert elements into list control present in a dialog box as follows:

```
int nIndex = 0;

for (int count = 0; count < arrResults.GetSize(); count++)
{
    nIndex = m_cListCtrl.InsertItem(count, _T(arrResults[count].ElementAt(0)));
    m_cListCtrl.SetItemText(nIndex, 1, _T(arrResults[count].ElementAt(1)));
}
```

However, when I try to retrieve data from `m_cListCtrl`, it always returns blank. Also, the `GetItemCount()` method also returns `0` items. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Following is the data retrieve code that I have written:

```
arrResults.SetSize(1);
arrResults[0].Add("Header1");
arrResults[0].Add("Header2");

TestDialog testDlg;
testDlg.FillControlList(arrResults); // This function has above code to add data to control list

EXPECT_EQ("Header1", queryDlg.m_cListCtrl.GetItemText(0, 0));
EXPECT_EQ("Header2", queryDlg.m_cListCtrl.GetItemText(0, 1));
```

The `GetItemText` function is returning blank string.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the code you posted, so the problem must be in the code that you didn't post. Show us more?

Comment: **ALWAYS** check return values of function calls -- is `nIndex` < 0? have you defined the columns of the List Control?

Comment: @RogerRowland - I have updated the question with code to get data from control list

Comment: @EdwardClements - Yes, I have defined the columns.

Comment: *"The GetItemText function is returning blank string"* - have you verified with the debugger that you **are** providing a valid string to `SetItemText`? I'm not sure that `_T()` macro is helping either - I didn't see that before, it should only be used around string literals.

Comment: Curious:  What styles are you using for the list control?

Comment: @RogerRowland - I am able to see the values in the control list when I run the application which means that it is getting populated correctly. But while debugging, one thing I noticed is that the variable m_cListCtrl is not showing these values. This has kept me in a confused state.

Comment: @rrirower - LVS_REPORT

Comment: Could someone please help me out here?.I am stuck with it for few days now.

Answer (score 0):

When you call FillControlList(), you are using testDlg object. But when you call GetItemText() you're using queryDlg object. You have inserted the items in one dialog and you're trying to get data from different object. Please check with that.